# Is it possible to write a C#-style custom attribute in node.js?

Tags: c#, node.js, attributes

I've used custom attributes in C# such as this

```
[Test]
[MyTestDetails("My favourite test")]
public void Check_how_soft_my_dog_is()
{
    // code stuff here
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=true, Inherited=false)]
public class MyTestDetailsAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Description { get; }

    public MyTestDetailsAttribute(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"#{Description}";
    }
}
```

I'd like to do a similar thing in node.js/Jest. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible, use this command `newrelic.addCustomAttribute` and you should be able to create a custom attribute